# Win Server 2008 - Reliability & Performance Monitor not restarting

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance-monitoring, perfmon

When setting up a user-defined data collection set which is written to a CSV file, I need to get the set to restart itself every hour, thus recreating the log file. Otherwise my log files will get too big. Before anyone recommends another solution, I have to do it like this :)

I have configured the data collection 'stop condition' tab as follows:

[image: Stop Condition]

However, the file just keep getting bigger and bigger.

Also, the equivalent functionality in Win 2003 works absolutely fine. Stopping and starting the counter using `logman.exe` works fine too.

Can someone tell me where to look for internal error logs related to the data collection sets, or help in any other way?

Many thanks in advance!

Ciaran

Comment: Guys, believe it or not I have had to resort to using a separate process to call `logman.exe` to restart the counters from the command line *sigh*.

Answer (score 2):

What does your "Directory" tab look like? A stock configuration would create a "000001", "000002", etc directory under your the root directory for the data collector set, by default. If the files in each directory are getting too big then you probably need a shorter per-directory duration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not using the directory tab, i.e I am not creating any new directories for each run. I am simply trying to reset the same file. You can see my directory as it stands here: http://i39.tinypic.com/14vo8xh.gif